# Software centre Problem

Tags: software-installation

i cannot install any software through software center and when i try to remove software center this appear

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: just google this `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?` error report.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: First of all i am new on ubuntu and this appear when run the command      dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process

Comment: Run the following commands `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

Comment: it say No such file or directory
Can you tell me more about this problem please

Comment: Did you run them one by one? If so, try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: it continue saying E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?